# c2dm push to many devices

Tags: android, push, android-c2dm

I planning the application pushes a newsletter to all registered users.

Number of users is approximately 200,000 ~ 300,000.

I'm caring about the traffic issue with google c2dm server.

Can I request to c2dm server in a loop with large number of users using HttpURLConnection?

Will I banned?

I heard something about in this case I must use http 1.1 protocol with keepAlive set true.

Comment: "How can I drive a large truck to this particular place? I heard the truck has to be red"... Not particularly useful.

Comment: @MarcB You mean, "something about in this case I must use http 1.1 protocol with keepAlive set true" is not useful, right?

Comment: one thing to keep in mind in all this is that your users might not all be in the same timezone, so it would be a good idea to not send push notifications at 3AM for some users. Try to spread it over 24h, and I'm sure Google will like that more too.

Comment: @zrgiu That's a considerable issue, but our users allmost in the same timezone, Korea. But your comment is useful to me, I will work with the timezone, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C2DM does have quotas, both on the messages per device and total number of messages. you can find the details here:
http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/quotas.html

as it says, 200k is the default limit but you can request a larger quota. i've done this at a company and it was no problem, but i can't say for sure how helpful they will be to the average developer.

as far as i know, there's no quota on the rate that you send them. you can send them as fast as the google servers will accept your requests.

> I planning the application pushes a newsletter to all registered
>   users.

you should make sure you aren't trying to push a payload through C2DM. that's clearly a misuse of the service. C2DM must be used to wake up the device only. in your case, the message itself should be "hey device there's a new newsletter on the server, go get it". assuming that's happening but a few times a day at most, it will be within the accepted use for C2DM.

Comment: I requested larger quota already. And I'm not using c2dm for payloads. I will load the message only for the user know the newsletter on the server. The traffic issue was my major issue and your answer gave me some tip, thanks.

Comment: @lulumeya I have been wondering the same thing about the rate at which we can send request to google servers.  Did you find any problems with rapidly sending the requests?

Comment: there is no limit on the rate you can send to google ... as fast as their servers accept the request. there is a limit on the total number per day.

Comment: @Patrick I did not tested real cases but, I used MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager in the Spring controller. I finished with looping in thread.